# Boolean.getBoolean() Vs System.getenv() in Java

Tags: java

```
Boolean.getBoolean("myvariable"); // where myvariable has been defined in the
                                  // Environment variable as Variable name:
                                  // myvariable
                                  // and Variable Value:true
```

The above call gives me output as `false`.
 If I use

```
 System.getenv("myvariable") ;
```

then it gives me output as `true`.

I am wondering why `Boolean.getBoolean("myvariable")` is not working.

Comment: I'm guessing the `testbootlog` in your comments is what is normally being passed to `getBoolean`?

Comment: If the method was having some sensible name like `Boolean.getSystemPropertyAsBoolean`, that will clear all confusion :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`System.getenv` returns an *environment variable*. That's not the same thing as `System.getProperty` which returns a *Java system property*.

`Boolean.getBoolean` uses the latter call, as documented:

> Returns true if and only if the system property named by the argument exists and is equal to the string "true". [...] A system property is accessible through `getProperty`, a method defined by the System class.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet , I was thinking both get the environment variable :)

Answer (score 3):

`Boolean.getBoolean("myvariable");` looks for a System Property called myvariable whereas `System.getenv("myvariable");` looks for an environment variable. Though similar, they're not the same.

Comment: the environment variablea and system properties are only "similar" in that they are sets of name-value pairs.  They come from completely different sources.