# Java get Boolean environment variable in application.conf

Tags: java, jpa

I would like to do something like this in my application.conf file.

```
# Debug SQL statements (logged using DEBUG level): 
jpa.debugSQL=${DEBUG_SQL}
```

I understand that the problem is that it interprets the environment variable as a string and not a Boolean (from here:  [Boolean.getBoolean() Vs System.getenv() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759313/boolean-getboolean-vs-system-getenv-in-java)), but as a Java novice I'm unsure what calls it is appropriate to make here to get this to work.

(I also tried setting DEBUG_SQL=0|1 in the environment, and that did not work.)

Thanks.

Comment: Who uses the `application.conf` file? Since everything in files is strings, the module that uses the conf file usually specifies the strings to use for true and false.

Comment: Oh, this made it easier than I expected.  I didn't realize it would interpret 'true' and 'false' strings from the env correctly, but it did.   (Like I said, no Java experience.)

Answer (score 2):

Presuming your config file loads those settings as properties you can go:

`boolean debugSQL = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("jpa.debugSQL"));`

note that parseBoolean is only true for the value "true" (case insensitive).  If you want to support more than that, check out BooleanUtils (http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#toBoolean(java.lang.String) )

It looks like you are using Play (based on the config filename) so you can use `Play.configuration.getProperty("jpa.debugSQL");` instead of `System.getProperty`

Comment: It turns out I could just use the strings true and false in the env and they were interpreted correctly, so I went with that approach.  Thanks, though!